# Compiling CUDA with clang - 'No available targets are compatible with triple "nvptx64-nvidia-cuda"'

Tags: c++, cuda, clang

I am trying to compile the example CUDA code `axpy.cu` from the [llvm docs](https://llvm.org/docs/CompileCudaWithLLVM.html#invoking-clang) using:

```
clang++ axpy.cu -o axpy --cuda-gpu-arch=sm_86 -L/usr/local/cuda-11.2/lib64 -lcudart_static -ldl -lrt -pthread
```

but I'm getting the following error:

> `error: unable to create target: 'No available targets are compatible with triple "nvptx64-nvidia-cuda"'`

What's going on here? I was able to compile CUDA with clang a day or two ago and now it's not working for some reason. I'm not sure what changed on my system.

I'm using clang 13 which should support CUDA 11.2.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I built llvm/clang from source without support for cuda. The solution is to use the `-DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="X86;NVPTX"` when building  llvm from source.